# Form of characteristic polynomial of a bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory

Apparently, it is true that the characteristic polynomial of a bipartite graph takes the form $g(t^2)$ for an even number of vertices and $tg(t^2)$ for an odd number of vertices for some polynomial $g(t)$.

I understand that the number of closed walks of length $\ell$ on a graph is $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^p \lambda_i^\ell$ for a $p \times p$ adjacency matrix. Since a bipartite graph has no closed walks of odd length, we know that $\lambda_1^\ell + \cdots + \lambda_p^\ell = 0$ for all odd $\ell$.

Now, I believe that the characteristic polynomial has the form $g(t^2)$ for an even number of vertices. For example, if $t=2$, then $P(t) = (t - \lambda_1)(t - \lambda_2) = t^2 - t(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2) + \lambda_1 \lambda_2$. Since $\lambda_1^1 + \lambda_2^1 = 0$ in this case, we have that $P(t) = t^2 - \lambda_1 \lambda_2$, which is a function of $t^2$. We could then use induction to show that this formula holds trues for any even $p$ (I think), because the product of functions of the form $g(t^2)$ will be a function of the form $g(t^2)$.

However, I don't even believe this formula is even true for an odd number of vertices. If $p = 3$, then 
\begin{eqnarray*}
P(t) &=& t^3 - t^2(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3) + t(\lambda_1 \lambda_3 + \lambda_2 \lambda_3 + \lambda_1 \lambda_2) - \lambda_1 \lambda_2 \lambda_3 \\
&=& t^3 + t(\lambda_1 \lambda_3 + \lambda_2 \lambda_3 + \lambda_1 \lambda_2) - \lambda_1 \lambda_2 \lambda_3 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
since $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3 = 0$ in this case. It seems like the $\lambda_1 \lambda_2 \lambda_3$ constant is preventing the characteristic polynomial from having the form $tg(t^2)$.

Any insight would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: In a bipartite graph with an odd number of vertices, one of the sides has to have more vertices than the other. Therefore the adjacency matrix can never have full rank, so one of the eigenvalues is always zero.

Answer (score 3):

Sure. Characteristic polynomial is a determinant of a matrix
\begin{equation*}
a_{i,j}=
\begin{cases} t & \text{if $i=j$,}
\\
1 &\text{if $i$ and $j$ are adjacent.}\\
0& \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
Consider any not vanishing summand $\prod a_{i,\pi(i)}$ of a determinant. Then permutation $\pi$ consists of several fixed points (corresponding to multiples $t$) and several even cycles (beacuse each cycle in our graph is even). From here we see, that power of $t$ has the same parity as number of vertices.